# Defekt Python-C linking leads code to deviates after relative number of loops and not absolute

Tags: python, c, parallel-processing, simd

For performance reasons I implemented a C function of an (adaptive) Gaussian filter. For a sanity check, I compared it to my old Python implementation. It seems to work well at first, but then starts to break down. Strangely, this does not seem to depend on the absolute number of frequencies evaluated, but somehow on the relative number. So I assume it has something to do with memory allocation or something? I am fairly new to C programming, so I may have overlooked a common problem.

Here is the signature of the function; I used gcc-13 to compile on macOS13.4 (intel chip)

```c
double complex* adapt_gf(double complex* rfft_, double* c_freq, double* freq_out, int n_freq_in, int n_freq_out)
```

Attached are two images showing the discrepancies I am talking of:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand most of that code, but I'll say that arrays in C index from `0`, not `1`.

Comment: I start at 1 as the zero indices should be treated differently

Comment: Do you see the same divergence in serial mode? (That is, if you disable OpenMP?)

Comment: Yes, I checked this as well, it is the same behaviour on visual inspection.

Comment: It's unlikely to be causing your divergence, but do not use `pow()` for small integer powers, positive or negative.  In particular, `pow(x, 2)` is much better written `x * x`.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I also double checked the `exp()` function to set things to zero if too small etc but this did not improve the behaviour

Comment: Side note: you don't need `filter_` as a dynamically allocated array, and the dynamic allocation and deallocation required is expensive.  You use only a single element of it at a time, and never return to any of those later, so all you need is a scalar variable of type `double`.

Comment: I assume you've compiled with clang or gcc `-Wall -fsanitize=undefined` and stuff like that. 
 When you disabled OpenMP, did you also disable `-ffast-math`?  If there's a precision problem or difference from what NumPy is doing, perhaps compile with `-ffp-contract=fast` or `off` to let it use FMA aggressively vs. not at all except when specified (by calling `fma(a,b,c)` instead of `a*b+c`, or equivalent for intrinsics).

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with your C code, and it appears to me to be a semantically faithful translation of Python version.  My fluency in AVX instrinsics is poor, however, so I'm looking mainly at the non-AVX version.  It is conceivable that the problem is in the caller, but if it is indeed localized in the function presented then you're presumably dealing a numerical instability and / or catastrophic loss of precision.  You might be able to trace that down with the help of a debugger, or simply by printing intermediate results.

Comment: Thank you @JohnBollinger and <at>Peter Cordes for your comments; I restarted and found indeed that the problem was the caller and not the function! Your advise is now also implemented!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I figured out, that the problem indeed was not the C implementation, but the function call in Python...

```py
c_lib.adapt_gf.argtypes = [
np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.complex128, ndim=1, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS'),  # rfft_
np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, ndim=1, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS'),    # c_freq
np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, ndim=1, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS'),    # freq_out
ctypes.c_int,  # n_freq_in
ctypes.c_int   # n_freq_out
]
c_lib.adapt_gf.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 2)
```

Instead of:

```py
# Define the argument types and return type of the function
c_lib.adapt_gf.argtypes = [
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 2),
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
    ctypes.c_int,
    ctypes.c_int
]
c_lib.adapt_gf.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 2)
```

solved the problem!